# v-bind isn't detecting the change in array content (vue js)

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm trying to change the `id` of an image after the user clicks on a button. Initially, the `id` of the element should be *B0_h*, but after the user clicks on a button, a value in an array should change to `true`. Initially all the array values are `false`, but once the value of the element in the array becomes true, the `id` should change to *B0_v*.

Using the Vue dev tools, I noticed that the value in the array is changing as expected, however, `v-bind` can't detect this change. From the `v-bind` perspective, the value of `B[0]` is still `false`. As a result, the `id` is still *B0_h*.

Here's my template:

```
<template>
    <div>
       <button type="button" id="button0" v-on:click="toggle('B0')"></button>
       <img src="../assets/img1.png" alt="A" v-bind:id="[A[0] === true ? 'A0_v' : 'A0_h']" >
       <img src="../assets/img2.png" alt="B" v-bind:id="[B[0] === true ? 'B0_v' : 'B0_h']">
    </div>
</template>
```

Here's my script:

```
<script>
export default {
  name: 'Demo',
  props: {},
  data: function(){
      return{
          A: [false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false],
          B: [false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false],
          playerTurn: true;
      }
  },
  methods: 
  {
    toggle(x)
    {
      if(x == 'B0' && this.playerTurn)
      {
        this.B[0] = true;
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong in here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is due to the handling of changes by Vue in arrays and objects. Vue won't track the change you're making. For this purpose it offers a special method: `set`. It takes 3 arguments: the array (or the object) that has to be changed, the index, and the value that should be set.

In your example it'll look like this:

```
Vue.set(this.B, 0, true);
```

Put this line instead of:

```
this.B[0] = true;
```

For more information please check the official [documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-set). This is a short excerpt:

> #### Vue.set( target, propertyName/index, value ) Arguments:
>
> - {Object | Array} target
> - {string | number} propertyName/index
> - {any} value
>
> **Returns:** the set value.
>
> **Usage:**
>
> Adds a property to a reactive object, ensuring the new property is
> also reactive, so triggers view updates. This must be used to add new
> properties to reactive objects, as Vue cannot detect normal property
> additions (e.g. this.myObject.newProperty = 'hi').